# How to pass values from examples for nested JSON in Karate in a scenario

Tags: api, frameworks, cucumber, karate, dsl

Here is json structure

{
"mfsCommonServiceRequest":
{
"mfsSourceInfo": {
"channelId": "22",
"surroundSystem": "1"
},
"mfsTransaction": {
"request": "9086544566665",
"service": "0",
"time": "1517218465350"
}
}
}

My code
Scenario Outline: To validate the response for crosscategory merchant list
Given headers req_headers
And url baseUrl
And path tokenApiUrl
And request { mfsCommonServiceRequest:, mfsTransactionInfo: }
When method post
Then status

```
Examples: 
  | mfsCommonServiceRequest!                                 | responseCode | mfsTransactionInfo!                                                          |
  | "mfsSourceInfo": {{"channelId:22","surroundSystem": "1"} |          200 | {"request:9086544566665","service": "0","time":"1517218465350"} } |
```

Comment: when i pass value, get unexpected token error

Comment: I can see one obvious mistake in the `request`, so I'll stop. please read this and try to re-format your question so that it is readable: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - also maybe you should stick to simple scenarios until you get a good feel for karate